# on-off-on soft latch transistor switch

Tags: transistors, switches, latch

I need to build a soft latching on-off-on switch that latch with momentary push buttons for use in on a 220v AC power line.
I mean a switch that have three momentary push buttons (2 buttons for `on` state and one for `off` state).
Is there a schematic for this?

Thanks

Comment: Why two "On" buttons? Do you need to be able to distinguish which one was used?

Comment: @DaveTweed: two on buttons for two separated outputs; I actually need to activate two devices (both off or one of them on - selectable) - I just need to be able to use each of them to select output line ( like an SPDT switch) or turn off both; actually I need a soft latching version of three position on-off-on SPDT switch

Comment: what is soft latching?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "soft latching" in this context. You can purchase three-position SPDT swiches that latch in neither "on" position, one "on" position or both "on" positions. What do you need that this doesn't cover?

Comment: Ah, I think I see ... you want the *functionality* of a three-position toggle switch, but you want to do it with momentary pushbuttons instead. I assume this means that if one device is on and someone pushes the other "on" button, the first device should turn off first.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I want a non-mechanical switch (mechanical switches get damaged very fast in my use)

Comment: @Andyaka: I mean a transistor circuit that latch on a state using a push button; like this: http://hackaweek.com/hacks/?p=344

Comment: @DaveTweed: yes that is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple relay logic. It will be simplest possible solution. If you get 220VAC relays, it can be made without additional power supply (sorry, the graphical symbols are not very good):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2OT4W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's close to what I was going to propose, but there are two problems: 1) It still uses *mechanical* switches, which the OP has ruled out, and more importantly, 2) It lacks the functionality of turning off Load1 when Load2 is turned on, and vice-versa. (You basically need a third set of N.C. contacts on each relay.)

Comment: Hm, as I understood the question, he needs 2 ON buttons in order to switch the loads on separately and one OFF to switch off both loads simultaneously. And also, he needed momentary push buttons. Exactly as I draw it. Let's wait for the asker to comment.